# Install Ubuntu from FTP server

Tags: 12.10, system-installation, ftp

When I install ubuntu I Start from USB flash disk and get image from FTP server, this is my USB flash disk's menu.lst:

```
"""
default 0 
timeout 3600  
fontfile /MiniPE/muifont.gz 
splashimage /MiniPE/bg.xpm.gz 

title ubuntu 12.04.32
kernel /ubuntu/ubuntu12.04.32/linux  mirror/protocol=ftp mirror/ftp/hostname=192.168.1.3 mirror/ftp/directory=/ubuntu12.04.32
initrd /ubuntu/ubuntu12.04.32/initrd.gz

title ubuntu 12.10.32
kernel /ubuntu/ubuntu12.10.32/linux mirror/protocol=ftp mirror/ftp/hostname=192.168.1.3 mirror/ftp/directory=/ubuntu12.10.32
initrd /ubuntu/ubuntu12.10.32/initrd.gz
"""
```

I put ubuntu-12.04.2-server-i386.iso and ubuntu-12.10-server-i386.iso in ftp server 192.168.1.3. so when start my computer from  USB flash disk it can download the installation image and install.

I used this method to install the 12.04 version successfully, but when I install 12.10 version it fails in the base system install stage, and returns this error message:

```
[Installation step failed]

An installation step failed. 
You can try to run the failing item again from the menu, or skip it and choose something else. 
The failing step is: Install the system.
```

I get the install logs and find there is a differences between the two install logs:

```
Oct 24 17:30:09 main-menu[407]: INFO: Menu item 'download-installer' selected
Oct 24 17:30:10 net-retriever: gpgv: 
Oct 24 17:30:10 net-retriever: Signature made Thu Feb 14 00:21:10 2013 UTC using DSA key ID FBB75451
Oct 24 17:30:10 net-retriever: gpgv: 
Oct 24 17:30:10 net-retriever: Good signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>"
Oct 24 17:30:10 net-retriever:
```

but in the 12.10 version install log:

```
Oct 24 08:48:22 main-menu[345]: INFO: Menu item 'live-installer' selected
Oct 24 08:48:22 base-installer: error: Could not find any live images
Oct 24 08:48:22 main-menu[345]: WARNING **: Configuring 'live-installer' failed with error code 1
Oct 24 08:48:22 main-menu[345]: WARNING **: Menu item 'live-installer' failed.
```

so why when I install the 12.10 version does it select 'live-installer' mode? How can I change it to 'download-installer' mode like the 12.04 version?

This problem has been bothering me for two days. Help me please! Thanks.